HID Omnikey 5427CK - how to manipulate data in CCID mode?
Is it possible to manipulate the CSN when the HID Omnikey Reader is in CCID mode?
I can do everything I need to when in Keyboard Wedge mode, and can add prefix, postfix, reverse CSN, change CSN format etc. So I'd like to be able to do all of this, but have it work when the reader is in CCID mode so that the output CSN is manipulated as needed.
Is this even possible, the developer guide has a lot of info about Keyboard Wedge config, but a simple definition of CCID mode that contains the following line:

CCID required an intelligent host and operates as a transparent PC/SC CCID reader where the host controls every aspect of the card communication.

Am I to understand then that in this mode, there is no control over the data from the reader itself and the host/ application must control all the logic?
"
